# Find Last time MediaScanner ran

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I am trying to find out if droid stores the last time the MediaScanner had been run.  Anyone know a way to check or if android stores that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation there is no way to find the last time the MediaScanner ran.  However, you can force a scan by using the scanFile() function:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if android saves the time log for the media scanner activity, however, you would know if the media scanner is already finished scanning by handling the ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED intent.